# In visual studio, my hotkey F12 doesn't expand my inherited functions

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm not exactly a programmer, but I've just started learning C# for Unity so I can design a simple game.

The tutorial I'm following says to press F12 to expand the inherited functions. When I press F12, nothing happens. One solution was to try CTRL F12, but that also didn't expand anything. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, since I'm very new to all of this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition for the `F12` shortcut is **Go To Definition**. This option can be seen with right clicking what you want to, well, see the definition.

[image: Command and shorcuts]

If you think you accidentaly changed the shortcut somehow, then you can check your actual shortcuts going on **Tools > Options... > Environment > Keyboard**

This is where you change your shortcuts if you want.

On the searchbox you can type `Definition` and it will show the command you are looking for.  [image: Shortcuts]

I also recommend checking **[Visual Studio's documment about shortcuts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&utm_source=vshelp)** for a list with all standard shortcuts.

Comment: Why make the assumption he's accidentally changed it? It doesnt work for me either and I have F12 mapped correctly to Go to definition.